# solaris: verify that access to all binaries is in accordance with the associated package

Tags: solaris, package-management

I need to verify that access (mode, owner) to all(!) binaries on a solaris 10 box are in accordance with the package that they came from. I could do something like

```
/usr/bin/find / -type f -perm -u+x,g+x,o+x -exec ls -l {} \; > /tmp/binaries.txt
```

and then iterate over the list and check with

```
pkgchk -l –p /path/to/binary
```

that the file is compliant. Of course, this could be scripted, but still this takes quite some time. I was wondering if there would be a tool or something that lets me go the other way around: for each package installed, check that its content is on disk like if was originally defined in the package (mode and ownership).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and that utility is also `pkgchk`, if you don't use the `-p` option to limit it to certain pathnames, but instead specify either the set of package names to check, or let it default to checking all packages installed on the machine.   From the man page:

> The first synopsis defined above is used to list or check the  contents and/or  attributes  of objects that are currently installed on the system, or in the indicated pkgmap. Package names may  be  listed  on  the command  line,  or by default, the entire contents of a machine will be checked.

So the syntax to handle 'for each package installed, check that its content is on disk like if was originally defined in the package (mode and ownership)' would simply be:

```
pkgchk -a
```

(The `-a` tells it to just check mode & ownership, not contents.  If you remove it to check contents as well, then you'll want to add `-n` to not check contents of editable files that are expected to change, such as config files.)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. So simple. Note to myself: rtfm.